# Optimization of SQL Statement

Tags: sql, firebird

I recently received a query that is taking too much time to run.
I would like your support on how to optimize it. Follow the statement
This database was developed long time ago.

```
SELECT x.CNPJ_CPF,
   X.PRODUCT,
   X.NAME_PRODUCT,
   Y.GROUP,
   Z.NAME,
   COUNT(*),
   X.VALOR,
   C.USER
FROM ATD222 X,
 CED001 Y,
 CED002 Z,
 CXD555 C
WHERE X.PRODUCT = Y.CODE
 AND Y.GROUP = Z.CODE
 AND X.CNPJ_CPF = C.CNPJ_CPF
 AND X.DATE >= '2020-01-01'
 AND X.DATE<='2020-01-30'
GROUP BY X.CNPJ_CPF,
     X.PRODUCT,
     X.NAME_PRODUCT,
     Y.GROUP,
     Z.NAME,
     X.VALOR,
     C.USER
```

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Can you please advise? I know its awkward statement. If you can help me to refactorate it, its well appreciated. Txs

Comment: Queries tend to be slow due to missing or incorrect indexes rather than how the query is written. BTW if your `X.DATE` column is not a `date`/`smalldate` (but actually `datetime`/`datetimeoffset`/`datetime2`) then your query has a bug because a value of `2020-01-30 13:30` will not be included in the results. **Always use exclusive upper-bounds** in date-range queries.

Comment: We can't help you unless you post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables and list all of the `CREATE INDEX` statements for all relevant indexes. Please also post your query's execution plan and your SQL Server Query Store configuration.

Comment: @Dai Firebird 3 and earlier have SQL standard `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone).

Comment: try reading optimization chapter at https://www.ib-aid.com/download/docs/hqbirduserguide2020.pdf?v=2 and https://www.ib-aid.com/en/articles/ibanalyst-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, some of the common causes of slow queries is

1. missing/bad statistics on the table for the optimizer
2. optimizer choosing a bad plan due to option 1 or doesn't consider data skew in the tables
3. relying on implicit conversions of the datatype, in the query. (Eg: a date column being compared with a varchar)
4. lack of indexes when an index might be suitable(Note: using an index might not always make your query faster though)
5. Lack of constraints, (yea, defining and keeping constraints optimize the query)

Sometime the query written by ORM's are so complex, when a simple one would have sufficed, eg: too many left joins when a join should have been used, or joining tables which are never used in the query etc..

To know what could be wrong in your query that takes time, it would be important to have a look at the execution plan, the constraints on your schema, indexes and datatypes on the table.